# Python number convert into list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am facing some issues in my python programming experience. I want to convert a number into python list in a for loop. If some python experienced programmer has any idea how to do this or can tell me what is wrong in my code. pls let me know.

l = `[3,6,9,2,11,14,13]`

I want to subtract last value to all values in a list. like this

```
for l1 in l:
    l1 = l[-1]-l
    print(l1)
```

problem is when print l1 outside I for loop show int not a list. it show this

```
In [60]: print(type(l1))
<class 'int'>

In [61]: print(l1)
0
```

and if i use if condtion to compare other list:

```
f = [7]
l = `[3,6,9,2,11,14,13]`

for l1 in l:
    l1 = l[-1]-l
    print(l1)     ## need list not int
    for f1 in f:
        if l1<=f:
            print(l1) ## print int not int list 
            for s in l:
                 f1 = l1+s
                 print(l1,"+",f1,"==", s)
```

I just need to know how to convert int into list in for loop and if condtion. i know this is not a good way to explain my problem. but if something is not clear pls let me know. thanks

Comment: You can't iterate over a list and change it at the same time. Building a new list based on the initial one is the way: `b = [var-l[-1] for var in l]`

Comment: just add input and expected output

Comment: We have `l = [3,6,9,2,11,14,13]`, some magic involving `l1`.  What do you want `l1` to look like after the magic.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel Comments are for seeking clarification, not answers.

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary, what's your expected output?

Comment: Also, what test are you trying to carry out with `l1<=f`?  Do you want it to return true if *any* element in l1 is less than the corresponding element in f? if *every* element in l1 is less than the corresponding element in f? if l1 is lexographically less than f (ie compare the first corresponding elements which are different)? if *every* element in l1 is less than *any* element in f.

Comment: @MartinBonner Where does it say that?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel somewhere in between the last code segment

Comment: @ArneRecknagel If you mean "where does it say comments are for clarifications..."?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment (towards the bottom "when shouldin't I comment" - second bullet.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I didn't know that, thank you. Then again, I sometimes give an 'easy answer' in order to receive feedback, and will transform it into an actual answer in case the answer was correct.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel can help to write code in list comprehensive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I want to subtract the last value of a list from all elements of the list" would translate to:

```
l1 = [x - l[-1] for x in l]
```

as a list comprehension. Alternatively, you could use arrays, like:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,2,3,1]
l1 = np.array(l)-l[-1] # l1 is now an array though, not a list
```

If, however, you just want each value individually, you just need to be careful about the variable names in your code (or just create the list as above and loop through it). Your loop should read:

```
for el in l:
    subel = l[-1]-el  # or el-l[-1]
    print(el)
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, your words and code don't match up. In your code, you don't seem to try subtracting the last element from each in the list, but also invert them, i.e.  `l[-1]-x`

Comment: It's not clear if the OP wants `x - l[-1]` or `l[-1] - x`.  The latter is what he has written, and "subtract to" rather than "subtract from" may suggest he wants the inverse too.  (OTOH, prepositions are always one of the hardest parts of a foriegn language to learn.)

Comment: well, I agree, but was hoping he could transfer as much. Anyways I'm not sure if this answers the whole question (I can't really fetch any information from his latter part of the post)

Answer (score -1):

Don't understand your question correctly, but from what i understood..

```
l = [3,6,9,2,11,14,13]

for l1 in l:
    l1 = l1-l[-1]
    print(l1)
```

this will give you output.

```
-10
-7
-4
-11
-2
1
0
```

is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: If you don't understand the question, ask for clarifications in the comments